# How to create two containers within a row that responsively keep equal heights?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Unfortuantely, the already answered questions on responsive background images and equal heights didn't solve my problem:

I am using Bootstrap 3 as a grid basis. I want to use an 8 column container and 4 column container within a full row. In the left container, I am using a background image which should be responsive. In the right container, I would like to use the background-color property instead of an image. I would like that both containers always keep the same height, when the screensize changes. At the moment I am using a fixed height of 450px, which logically creates a white gap between both containers on smaller screensizes. `

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any idea how to ensure that both containers always keep the same height without any white gaps?

**HTML**

```
<div class="row"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8" id="header_left"></div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4" id="header_right">

        <h1 class="text-center">Ipsum Lorum</h1>

        <p class="lead text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, 
        sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

        <p class="text-justify">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. 
        At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header_left {

background: url('.../img/header_img.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;

-moz-background-size: 100% auto;
-webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
background-size: 100% auto;
height: 450px;
}

#header_right {

background-color: green;
height: 450px;

}
```

Comment: Seems to already work that way: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/V6zAJ/

Comment: If you change the size of the result window, you will see that it is not working responsively as intended.

Comment: I posted a very nice solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## DEMO http://jsbin.com/aZuGORuP/1/

### http://jsbin.com/aZuGORuP/1/edit?html,css,output

```
<div class="header-wrapper">

  <div id="header_left">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/767x400" class="img-fullwidth visible-sm visible-xs"/>
  </div>


<div id="header_right">
  <div class="content">
     <h1 class="text-center">Ipsum Lorum</h1>

    <p class="lead text-center">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>

    <p class="text-justify">At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>




.img-fullwidth {width:100%;}

.header-wrapper {
    background-color:royalblue;
 }

 #header_right .content {
   color:#fff;
   padding:5%;
 }

  #header_right h1 {margin-top:0;}

  @media (min-width:992px) { 

 .header-wrapper {
    background-color:royalblue;
    display:table;
    height:450px;
 }

#header_left {
  width: 60%;
  display:table-cell;
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1200x800') 50% 50% no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
}

#header_right {
  width: 40%;
  display:table-cell;

 }

}
```

Comment: Your solution with the invisible image on larger resolutions is achieving the desired visual effect. The only downside is that it does not work with Bootstraps grid system, i.e. class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8" and class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4", which nicely splits the screen in the middle on medium resolutions.

Comment: Yes, you can't do what you want with the Bootstrap grid system. Their grids are not equal height. You could use flexbox to do this, but that would only be supported on IE 10+. The 50% split is easy enough too. http://jsbin.com/aZuGORuP/7/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot, Christina. Very well answered.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using height:450px with max-height:450px for both the #header_left and #header_right.

Comment: max-height:450px applied on #header_left makes the background disappear. Unfortuantely not working...

Comment: Are you using it with height:450?  You need to set both values.

Comment: Have a look at the jsfiddle of isherwood: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/V6zAJ/ it is exactly like that at the moment.

Comment: How about using background-size:cover rather than background-size:100% auto?

Comment: That fixes the layout issue, but it makes the background image unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

Change to the cover value:

```
#header_left{
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and add styles for .text-center:

```
.text-center{
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```